# How can 2FA help prevent formjacking?

Tags: web-browser, webserver, multi-factor, websites, formjacking

[This article](https://www.avira.com/en/blog/formjacking-what-it-is-and-how-to-protect-yourself) by Avira (part of NortonLifeLock) claims that 2FA (2-Factor Authentication) may be sufficient to protect against formjacking:

> Enable 2-Factor Authentication: Create strong and complex passwords to protect all your accounts. If possible, configure 2-factor authentication, as this may be enough to protect you from a formjacking attack.

How can 2FA protect against formjacking?  If either device involved in a transaction is compromised with formjacking code, it seems like 2FA will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't protect you against form-jacking, it protects you against someone gaining access to your account despite form-jacking.

Most 2FA mechanisms utilize a native apps containing a secret to generate time-based one-time passwords (continuously replacing text messages). These TOTPs work completely offline, making form-jacking virtually impossible (which is already quite difficult to pull of native apps).